# Swift: Access an enum from another viewController class

Tags: ios, swift, enums, xcode9.4

I have two viewcontrollers (A and B). In main viewcontroller (A) I'm trying to set a variable and the possible values are enums. The following code is in second viewcontroller(B)

Code:

```
enum Numbers: String {
    case one = "One"
    case two = "two"
    case three = "three"
}

var numberSelected: Numbers? = .one
```

I'm trying to load the second ViewController(B) and set numberSelected with the value depending on selection in the Main viewController:

```
func loadSecondoViewController() {
    let storyBoard = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ColorsViewController")
    guard let secondVC =  storyBoard as? SecondViewController else {return}
    
    secondVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.flipHorizontal
    switch languageSelected {
    case .one:
        secondVC.numberSelected = secondVC.
        
   self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

On this line:

`secondVC.numberSelected = secondVC.`

I can not access Numbers (enums).

Anyone know how can we set numberSelected from the main viewcontroller?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access `Numbers` because enums nested in classes are `static`. You can't access static members through an instance of that class. You can access it normally like this:

```
secondVC.numberSelected = SecondViewController.Numbers.one
```

In fact, you can just write:

```
secondVC.numberSelected = .one
```

If the type of `languageSelected` is also `SecondViewController.Numbers`, you can do this in one line, without a switch statement:

```
secondVC.numberSelected = languageSelected
```

Answer (score 0):

Create enum in any other class like constant class and in which class you wAnt to use  enum just create object of that enum and use with that object.

Comment: Can you post and example?

Comment: this is your enum:
enum checkUSerType : String{
        case kSignUpUser = "signUp"
        case kLoginUser = "Login"
    }
Create Object in using class
    var userType = checkUSerType.kLoginUser

Comment: create object or same enum in another class and from segue or object just set the value you want assign
            destinationVC.userType = userType == checkUSerType.kSignUpUser ? .kSignUpUser : .kLoginUser